# How can I render HTML in a Silverlight 5 app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control, silverlight-5.0, html-rendering

I'm currently working on a project that renders emails in HTML format to a Silverlight 5 app.  The app is intended to be viewed via a web browser and not an 'Out of browser' app.  The WebBrowser control was initially used,  but I'm having issues with it.  A message stating that IE needs elevated permissions and such.  After reading how to properly implement the WebBrowser control by signing the .xap file and installing certificates it seems to work when I run it locally, but when I publish to the server (Windows Server 2008), it doesn't seem to work.

I tried to implement an alternative I found -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx, but that didn't seem to work as the HTML I'm trying to render has many tags not supported in that example.

I also took a look at the Frame control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.95).aspx but not sure if that would solve my problem either.

So if anyone can guide me into the right direction of either how I can get the WebBrowser control to work when pushed to the server or perhaps another alternative it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you really need the embedded web rendering, you need to enable elevated priviledges, which, in browser, requires signing + a group policy setting. You can find several questions on the subject on SO already.

Comment: Yeah after more research I was able to find out that I just need to setup a certificate server in our intranet.  Which then I can use to sign the .xap file and with a group policy setting should be good to go.